# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in Node JS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I am new in Node js. i'm trying to make CRUD app in node js using mysql. but i am facing error which i can't understood or handle. Please Help. and thankx in adv.

I can't read input field value from ejs page to server.js Page.

My server.js file is given below

```
        // server.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "tuts_rest"
});

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// about page 
app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/about');
});

app.post('/insert', function(req,res){

    con.connect();

    console.log(req.body.name);

    con.query("INSERT INTO users(name,email,country) VALUES('"+req.body.name+"','"+req.body.email+"','"+req.body.country+"')", function(err, results) {
      if (!err)
        res.send('Inserted Successfully!')
      else
        throw error;
    });

    con.end();
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('8080 is the magic port');
```

I'm sending following Data using form

```
<form role="form" action="/insert" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lname">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="country">Country:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="country" name="country">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and Error is given as below

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\node\basic\server.js:40:22
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\xampp\htdocs\node\basic\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\xampp\htdocs\node\basic\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\xampp\htdocs\node\basic\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\xampp\htdocs\node\basic\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\xampp\htdocs\node\basic\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (E:\xampp\htdocs\node\basic\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\xampp\htdocs\node\basic\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (E:\xampp\htdocs\node\basic\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\xampp\htdocs\node\basic\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: does `console.log(req.body.name);` output anything?

Comment: no.. it returns nothing..@Jehy

Comment: So that's the problem. Try sending `name` parameter when you post data to your webserver.

Comment: also it terminates server..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requiring `body-parser` does not do anything.
You need to make express actually use it.

```
// accept url encoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

// accept json 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

**Note:**

- Your queries are wide open for sql injection. Use prepared statements or use a query builder like [knex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/knex) to do it for you.
- Instead of creating and managing connections one-by-one, use connection pooling. To do so, use`mysql.createPool` instead of `mysql.createConnection`

Comment: it works but leaves message like, body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares... What it means?

Comment: Don't think you used `extended : true`. Add it and the warning would go away.